# Как добавить гет параметр при загрузке странице Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется ссылка  http://example.com/sale/. Sale эта страница товара где выводится товары со скидкой, и имеет шаблон с названием sale.php. Чтобы вывести  товары со скидкой требуется get параметр onsales=salesonly. Как можно сделать так чтобы, при загрузке страницы гет параметр автоматически подставлялся?

Comment: При выводе товаров добавьте параметр по умолчанию который вам нужен, а в случае если вам нужен будет другой, вы просто переопределите его

Comment: Хмм, это все  short кодом выводится WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно "прибить" намертво добавте редирект в functions.php активной темы:

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_from_to_sale' );
    function redirect_from_to_sale() {
        if ( is_page( 'sale' ) ) {
            wp_redirect(  home_url('/sale/?onsales=salesonly' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Если страница 'sale' не обычная страница(архив и т.д.), то для срабатывания условия замените хук `is_page()` на соответствующий.